# Adding pictures with QField into QGIS (parent primary keys are not available)

Tags: qgis, qfield

After programming in QGIS, the following error appears in the QField when I try to make a picture:

> Cannot add child feature: parent primary keys are not available.

It's probably just a minor flaw in relationships or something like that. I just don't find it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a 1:n relation (Bäume to Bäume_Bilder). Each feature in Bäume can have unlimited pictures. Check my relation options:

[image]

In the Layer properties of Bäume_Bilder you have to set the field "ID" (the referencing field of "Bäume_Bilder" to Widget Type: Relation Reference like shown:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you the issue. Whatever   field you use as the primary key, has no value. If this occurs when you try to add photos to existing features, its because you have not populated the field. If its for new features, you've forgotten to set the default value (something like uuid() or a sequence).